# Exclude certain URL's from ISAPI Rewrite 3's URL Rewrite

Tags: windows, drupal-6, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I'm building a Drupal CMS website on IIS 6 and using ISAPI Rewrite 3 to make the url's more readable. My problem is that I have a virtual directory located within the Drupal site but which points to a local directory outside of the Drupal website folder. I do not want ISAPI Rewrite to rewrite urls pertaining to this virtual folder. For example:

**www.domain.com** - rewrite everything

**www.domain.com/pdf/** - exclude from url rewrites

Is this possible?

Other info:
Drupal version 6.19 **--** ISAPI Rewrite 3 **--** IIS 6 **--** Windows Server 2003 R2

Edit #1: the folder to be excluded contains pdf documents. Currently when I try to open a pdf via url (e.g. www.domain.com/pdf/thisdocument.pdf) it gives me a 404 page not found error - handled by ISAPI Rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can use RewriteCond for this (http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteCond.htm):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(^/pdf/)
RewriteRule (Your rule here)
```

You can also use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (Your rule here)
```

To exclude any existing files or directories from your RewriteRule.